# Bitlocker hide menu

Tags: group-policy, bitlocker

I configure a policy to save bitlocker key into AD DS which is working fine but I would like to remove this menu which show when you try to bitlocker the PC.

I dont want to save key on USB, Network location or print. I just want to save the Key into AD DS.

Thank for your help in advace

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KWr26.png)

Comment: The recovery password saved to Active Directory is not related to the dialog. If you to configure BitLocker unattended without prompts, use the manage-bde command and specify the required key protectors.

Comment: Thats not true in my previouse company we click on bitlocker and then it does it check e.g. enabling tpm and then it start bitlocker a pc, I never seen these menu before

Comment: I believe the "Require additional authentication at startup" policy is where you can disable the PIN/key.

Comment: Thank you that worked. Remove Pin and Key from setting and its working fine now